# Changing input value inside "input" event handler prevents "change" event firing in Chrome and IE (but not in Firefox)

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome, internet-explorer, firefox

In the following code I have "input" event handler that changes the value of the input as the user types. I also have "change" event handler to keep track of any changes made to this field. For some reason "change" event doesn't fire in Chrome and IE when the user leaves the field. Why is that and how to make it work in all major browsers?

Also note that it's not acceptable to trigger "change" event manually every time "input" event fires.

**EDIT**: "change" event seems to fire in Chrome only if `transform` function does not change the resulting string in any way. So if I type lower case letters and focus out after every character, "change" fires only for indexes 0, 2, 4 ...

Link to fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/3hqxx2pr/

```js
function transform(s) {
    var r = "";
    for (var i = 0; i < s.length; i++) {
        r += i & 1 ? s[i].toUpperCase() : s[i];
    }
    return r;
}

$(document).ready(function(){
  
    $("#in").on("change", function() {
        console.log("changed"); // works only in ff
    });

    $("#in").on("input propertychange", function() {
        $("#in").val(transform($("#in").val()));
    });
  
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input id="in"/>
```

Comment: @Regent It seems to work somewhat randomly in Chrome.

Comment: Most probably problem is in changing `<input>` value. [Example without changing value](http://jsfiddle.net/orxwgapo/1/).

Comment: I mean modifying `<input>` value inside `input` event handler.

Comment: @Regent Indeed. Any ideas how to circumvent this limitation?

Comment: Well, I can suggest to use `transform` function in `change` event handler: [example](http://jsfiddle.net/orxwgapo/2/). I haven't found any other ways yet.

Answer (score 0):

Trigger change yourself

```
$("#in").val(transform($("#in").val())).change();
```

or

```
$("#in").val(transform($("#in").val())).trigger("change");
```

---

Based on a edit and restriction you made:

```
$("#in").on("input propertychange", function() {
    var inp = $(this);
    var orgVal = inp.val();
    var transVal = transform(orgVal);
    if (orgVal !== transVal) {
        inp.val(transVal).trigger("change");
    }
});
```

Comment: What about: _Also note that it's not acceptable to trigger "change" event manually every time "input" event fires._?

Comment: Well it is only being triggered in my larger example when the value is changed by JavaScript which by definition does not trigger change which the OP is seeing in 2 of the browsers. If someone knows how to get around that, I will delete this. ;)

Comment: Tried your code and now it fires after every other character (tried FF and Chrome). That's still not what I want, although it's no longer "every time input event fires" :)